# Delete other user except current_user in rails app using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to list all the users who are using my application and delete only those that i want. But every time when i try to delete my user it passes `localhost:3000/users.2` instead of `localhost:3000/users/2`.

And also it doesn't delete selected user rather it delete current user. But i don't want to delete current user.

I have not modified any controllers or models but only used following codes in my view to list and delete user.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr class="bg-primary">
        <th>S.N.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Created at</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <% @users.each_with_index do |u, i| %>
          <% if current_user.email != u.email %>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><%= (@page.to_i - 1) * @perpage + i+1 %></td>
                <td>
                  <% if u.first_name.present?%>
                      <%= u.first_name.slice(0, 1).capitalize + u.first_name.slice(1..-1) %>
                  <% end %>
                  <% if u.middle_name.present? %>
                      <%= u.middle_name.slice(0, 1).capitalize + u.middle_name.slice(1..-1) %>
                  <% end %>
                  <% if u.last_name.present? %>
                      <%= u.last_name.slice(0, 1).capitalize + u.last_name.slice(1..-1) %>
                  <% end %>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <%= u.email %>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <%= u.created_at %>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a data-confirm="Are you sure to delete" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="<%= user_registration_path(u)%>">
                    <span class="fa-delete">
                      <i class="fa fa-trash fa-th-large fa-2x"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </table>
```

error when i try to delete other user except current_user

[image: error when i try to delete other user except current_user]

Comment: Please have a look [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289299/rails-how-to-destroy-users-created-under-devise) might be it would be helpful.

Comment: It would be help you- [Delete users using devise gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012842/whats-the-path-to-destroy-registration-with-devise)

Comment: sorry but it didn't work... is there any other idea

Answer (score 1):

Just check for current user with `<% unless u == current_user %>` for delete link

You can show other data to current_user

```
<% unless u == current_user %>
  <a data-confirm="Are you sure to delete" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="<%= user_registration_path(u)%>">
    <span class="fa-delete">
      <i class="fa fa-trash fa-th-large fa-2x"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
<% end %>
```

If you don't want to show any data

Replace

```
<% if current_user.email != u.email %>
```

with

```
<% unless current_user == u %>
```

Comment: its not the problem... problem is that i want to delete only other user except current_user but its not happening...when ever i try to delete other listed user it deletes current user and show error message.... error message is given in the picture above......check it

Answer (score 0):

If you just try to delete a user, I think you already have the logic for it, just change the `a` tag for a `link_to` helper method:

```
<% unless u == current_user %>
 <%= link_to user_registration_path(u), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure to delete?", rel: "nofollow" do %>
   <span class="fa-delete">
     <i class="fa fa-trash fa-th-large fa-2x"></i>
   </span>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This way is cleaner and more railsy

Answer (score 0):

The route you are trying to delete a user comes with Devise and used for deleting only current user. 
To delete any user, you have to create a new controller that has destroy action in it. After that, add this controller/action to your routes and then you will be able to delete any user you want by using new the route.

Example controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user != user
     if user.destroy
       flash[:success] = "Successfully deleted"
     else
       flash[:error] = "Error"
     end
    end
    redirect_to your_users_path
   end
end
```

In your routes:

```
 match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
```

And then when creating the link:

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", admin_destroy_user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```