# How to use Sweet Alert to send ajax DELETE request in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sweetalert

Problem 1: When I click the link, the sweet alert modal pops up for a split second, disappears, and redirects to route. Not sure why the modal is only flashing when it should stay until option chosen. I need user to confirm yes or no to delete account. If no then cancel, if yes than redirect to route.

[image]

Problem 2: I also understand from looking at this [doc](https://gorails.com/forum/how-to-use-sweet-alert-to-replace-standard-confirm-dialog) that in order to use the DELETE method in Sweet Alert I have to use an ajax request. Not sure what to put in url since I am using a rails route with a DELETE method, in order to get the ajax to redirect to that route to delete account.

Any help appreciated. Been working on this two days now.

Edit: Rails version 4.2.4, Sweet Alert version 1

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Account',registration_path(current_user), method: :delete, data: { behavior: 'delete' } %>



$("[data-behavior='delete']").on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

  swal ({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'You will not be able to recover your account!',
      icon: 'warning',
      buttons: [ 'Yes', 'No']
  }).then(isNo => {
  if(isNo) return;
      $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: "JSON",
        method: "DELETE",
        success: ()=> {
            swal('Deleted!', 'Your account has been deleted.', 'success');
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was simpler than I thought. Use a form_tag and in jQuery use `$(this).parents('form');` If you try to grab the form by the id to submit, it won't work. Did not need to use AJAX.

HTML

```
<%= form_tag(registration_path(current_user), { method: :delete, id: "deleteForm" }) do %>
  <button id="delete" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete Account</button>
<% end %>
```

jQuery

```
 $('#delete').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var form = $(this).parents('form');
          swal ({
              title: 'Are you sure?',
              text: 'You will not be able to recover your account!',
              icon: 'warning',
              closeModal: false,
              allowOutsideClick: false,
              closeOnConfirm: false,
              closeOnCancel: false,
              buttons: [ 'No', 'Yes']
          }).then((willDelete) => {
              if (willDelete) {
                  swal("Your account has been deleted!", {
                      icon: "success",
                  });
                  form.submit();
              } else {
                  swal("Your account is safe.");
              }
          });
      });
```